# How to disable pevious date in html form using min attribute of date datatype

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to set min attribute to today's date and disable previous date in datepicker in html view page C#

```
<input type="date" min="new Date().today()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't `min` attribute that can disable the previous date without writing any js script.

You can try to use JQuery library datepicker API which supports disabling the previous date by [minDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate:0
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


Datepicker:<input id="datepicker1" type="text" required value="">
```